# Guessing Game - Tkinter Module

Tags: python, tkinter

I created a code in Python to present a Guess game of numbers between 1 and 100. I wanted to implement this game in a graphical interface, using the Tkinter module. I had an idea, I created a code using tkinter, but after that I crashed. My question is, how to "merge" the two codes that were created into one, to create this graphical interface?

Tkinter part.

```
from tkinter import *
import random

i = Tk()

i.title('Guess Game')
i.geometry("400x200")

texto = Label(i, text = "Welcome to the Guess Game")
texto.pack()

texto = Label(i, text = "You have 10 chances to hit the number I'm thinking")
texto.pack()
texto = Label(i, text = "This is a value between 1 and 100. So, come on!")
texto.pack()

form = Entry(i, width=3)
form.pack()

b = Button(i, text ="Execute", fg= "green")
b.pack()

i.mainloop()
```

Second part

```
import random

n = random.randrange(1, 101)
nrepete = []
estado1 = 7  # início
estado2 = 7


def SetStatus(tentativa):

    global estado2

    if abs(n - palpite) == 1:
        estado2 = 6  # Very Fucking Hot
    if abs(n - palpite) == 2 or abs(n - palpite) == 3:
        estado2 = 5  # Very Hot
    if abs(n - palpite) >= 4 and abs(n - palpite) <= 6:
        estado2 = 4  # Hot
    if abs(n - palpite) >= 7 and abs(n - palpite) <= 9:
        estado2 = 3  # Warm
    if abs(n - palpite) >= 10 and abs(n - palpite) <= 15:
        estado2 = 2  # Cold
    if abs(n - palpite) >= 16 and abs(n - palpite) <= 25:
        estado2 = 1  # Very Cold
    if abs(n - palpite) >= 26:
        estado2 = 0  #  Freezing


def FornecerPista():
    if estado1 == 7:
        if estado2 == 0:
            print('Freezing!')
        if estado2 == 1:
            print('Very cold!')
        if estado2 == 2:
            print('Cold!')
        if estado2 == 3:
            print('Warm!')
        if estado2 == 4:
            print('Hot!')
        if estado2 == 5:
            print('Very hot!')
        if estado2 == 6:
            print('Very fucking hot!')
    if estado1 - estado2 == 0:
        if estado2 == 0:
            print('Seu palpite continua congelando!')
        if estado2 == 1:
            print('Seu palpite continua muito frio!')
        if estado2 == 2:
            print('Seu palpite continua frio!')
        if estado2 == 3:
            print('Seu palpite continua morno!')
        if estado2 == 4:
            print('Seu palpite continua quente!')
        if estado2 == 5:
            print('Seu palpite continua muito quente!')
        if estado2 == 6:
            print('Seu palpite continua fervendo!')
    if estado1 - estado2 > 0:
        if estado2 == 0:
            print('Ops, seu palpite deu uma esfriada e agora está congelando!')
        if estado2 == 1:
            print('Ops, seu palpite deu uma esfriada e agora está muito frio!')
        if estado2 == 2:
            print('Ops, seu palpite deu uma esfriada e agora está frio!')
        if estado2 == 3:
            print('Ops, seu palpite deu uma esfriada e agora está morno!')
        if estado2 == 4:
            print('Ops, seu palpite deu uma esfriada e agora está quente!')
        if estado2 == 5:
            print('Ops, seu palpite deu uma esfriada e agora está muito quente!')
    if estado1 - estado2 < 0:
        if estado2 == 1:
            print('Ops, seu palpite deu uma esquentada e agora está muito frio!')
        if estado2 == 2:
            print('Ops, seu palpite deu uma esquentada e agora está frio!')
        if estado2 == 3:
            print('Ops, seu palpite deu uma esquentada e agora está morno!')
        if estado2 == 4:
            print('Ops, seu palpite deu uma esquentada e agora está quente!')
        if estado2 == 5:
            print('Ops, seu palpite deu uma esquentada e agora está muito quente!')
        if estado2 == 6:
            print('Ops, seu palpite deu uma esquentada e agora está fervendo!')


for tentativa in range(1, 11):
    while True:
        try:
            palpite = input('Tentativa' + str(tentativa) + ':')
            palpite = int(palpite)
            nrepete.append(palpite)
            if (palpite < 1) or (palpite > 100):
                raise ValueError
            if nrepete.count(palpite) >= 2:
                raise NameError
            else:
                break
        except NameError:
            print('Esse valor já foi testado! Tente de novo.')
        except ValueError:
            print('Invalid value! Try again.')

    if palpite == n:
        print('\nCongratulations !')
        print('\nYou hit the number', n, 'after', tentativa, 'tentativa(s)!')
        break
    if tentativa == 1:
        SetStatus(tentativa)
    if tentativa > 1:
        estado1 = estado2
        SetStatus(tentativa)
    FornecerPista()

    if tentativa == 10 and palpite != n:
        print('\nLamento, mas após', tentativa, 'tentativas')
        print('Você não conseguiu acertar o número', n, 'que eu estava pensando!')
```

Comment: Can i ask what is "SetStatus" in your 2nd part of the script? it is not defined when i try to run it

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. I put "Submit" instead of "SetStatus". The correct is "def SetStatus(tentativa). "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've put together some code that does what you want.  I've also made some other changes to the code that aren't necessary to make my solution work, but you should strongly consider implementing them, as they are better practice.  The way I merged the code was by doing the following:

- Adding an action listener to your execute button (google action listener to learn more)
- Using messageboxes to display output instead of printing
- Putting the "action code" (the code that is analyzing the guesses and such) in a function that executes whenever the execute button is hit

The general changes I made to the code were making use of elif statements and using lists to store messages rather than doing `if x == 3, then print("blablabla")` Use elif statements because there is no sense in evaluating conditions that you know will fail (for example, if `x == 3` executes, then there is no need to check if `x == 4` will execute - we know it won't.)  I encourage you to research if/elif/else conditions more in depth so that my comment makes more sense.

For starters, this is the solution: run it on your computer and see if you like it.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
from tkinter import messagebox

n = random.randrange(1, 101)
nrepete = []
estado1 = 7  # início
estado2 = 7

tentativa = 0


def execute():
    global tentativa, estado2, estado1
    if tentativa < 10:  # only play if you still have turns
        palpite = form.get()
        try:
            palpite = int(palpite)
            nrepete.append(palpite)
            if (palpite < 1) or (palpite > 100):
                raise ValueError
            if nrepete.count(palpite) >= 2:
                raise NameError

            tentativa += 1
            if palpite == n:
                message = "Congratulations!  You hit the number {} after {} tentativa(s)!".format(n, tentativa)
                messagebox.showinfo("You win!", message)

            else:
                SetStatus(tentativa, palpite)
                if tentativa > 1:
                    estado1 = estado2

                message = FornecerPista()
                messagebox.showinfo("Status", message)

                if tentativa == 10 and palpite != n:
                    message = "Lamento, mas após {} tentativas. Você não conseguiu acertar o número {} que eu estava pensando!".format(
                        tentativa, n)
                    messagebox.showinfo("Game over", message)

        except NameError:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", 'Esse valor já foi testado! Tente de novo.')
        except ValueError:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", 'Invalid value! Try again.')


    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("Game over", "You've already lost.  The answer was {}".format(n))


def SetStatus(tentativa, palpite):
    global estado2
    x = abs(n - palpite)

    if x == 1:
        estado2 = 6  # Very Fucking Hot
    elif x == 2 or x == 3:
        estado2 = 5  # Very Hot
    elif 4 <= x <= 6:
        estado2 = 4  # Hot
    elif 7 <= x <= 9:
        estado2 = 3  # Warm
    elif 10 <= x <= 15:
        estado2 = 2  # Cold
    elif 16 <= x <= 25:
        estado2 = 1  # Very Cold
    elif x >= 26:
        estado2 = 0  # Freezing


def FornecerPista():
    message = ""
    if estado1 == 7:
        messages = ["Freezing!", "Very cold!", "Cold!", "Warm!", "Hot!", "Very hot!", "Very fucking hot!"]
        message = messages[estado2] + "\n"
    elif estado1 == estado2:
        messages = ['congelando', 'muito frio', "frio", "morno", "quente", "muito quente", "fervendo"]
        message += "Seu palpite continua {}!".format(messages[estado2])

    elif estado1 > estado2:
        messages = ['congelando', 'muito frio', "frio", "morno", "quente", "muito quente"]
        message += "Ops, seu palpite deu uma esfriada e agora está {}!".format(messages[estado2])
    else:
        messages = ['muito frio', "frio", "morno", "quente", "muito quente", "fervendo"]
        message += "Ops, seu palpite deu uma esquentada e agora está".format(messages[estado2 - 1])

    return message


i = Tk()

i.title('Guess Game')
i.geometry("400x200")

texto = Label(i, text="Welcome to the Guess Game")
texto.pack()

texto = Label(i, text="You have 10 chances to hit the number I'm thinking")
texto.pack()
texto = Label(i, text="This is a value between 1 and 100. So, come on!")
texto.pack()

form = Entry(i, width=3)
form.pack()

b = Button(i, text="Execute", fg="green", command=execute)
b.pack()

i.mainloop()
```

### How does it work:

By adding the `command = execute` line to your execute button construction, the execute() function is called whenever the button is hit.  The execute function is all of the action code, plus a few modifications.  To get the guessed number, I call `form.get()` to get the contents of the entry box called form.  Instead of printing messages, I display them using the tkinter messagebox.  Once again, there are tons of resources online about the messagebox so I won't explain it too much.  I can't promise this works perfectly because I don't speak much spanish (and thus wasn't able to effectively test it), but at the very least, this will provide a link between your two segments of code.  You can obviously modify it until it works for you.

Another solution that doesn't involve the messagebox would be updating a label with a string variable.  Feel free to google that as well.  As a note about the other answer involving threading, it is certainly better practice (I myself use it), but I wouldn't worry about that for this project.  The computations are practically instant, so your frame shouldn't freeze.  If this does occur, then you can go ahead and use threading.  Another note: I would try to avoid using global variables if you can help it.  Most of the time, creating functions and using return statements is much cleaner.